# Where does this term come from when integrating this inequality?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, convex-optimization

From *Convex Optimization* by Boyd & Vandenberghe:

> Let $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be continuous and twice differentiable.
>
> Given this inequality
>
> $$\tilde f''(t) \le \tilde f''(0) + tL \|\Delta x_{\text{nt}}\|  \le \lambda(x)^2 + t\frac{L}{m^{3/2}}\lambda(x)^3 $$ where $$\tilde f''(0) = \lambda(x)^2 \text{ and }\lambda(x)^2 \ge m\|\Delta x_{\text{nt}}\|_2^2 \text{ and } \tilde f(t) = f(x + t\Delta x_{\text{nt}}) \text{ and } t \ge 0 $$  $$ \text{and } \lambda(x)^2 = \Delta x_{\text{nt}}^T \nabla f(x) \Delta x_{\text{nt}}$$
>
> Integrating this inequality gives
>
> $$\tilde f'(t) \le \tilde f'(0) + t\lambda(x)^2 + t^2\frac{L}{2m^{3/2}}\lambda(x)^3$$
>
> where $\tilde f'(0) = - \lambda(x)^2$

Where did the $\tilde f'(0)$ come from?  Shouldn't it just be the last two terms?

Comment: I assume you are integrating $\int_0^{t} f''(\tau) \text{d} \tau$? In that case, that
term should simply come from the fact that $\int_a^b \partial_s g(s) \text{d}s = g(b) - g(a)$.

Comment: I completely forgot about the left side of the inequality.  That makes sense now.